# Woocommerce SKU on ALL products page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Woocommerce on wordpress

When i List ALL the products using a Product catergory of ALL Products and every product is listed OR i use any of the categorys

I get a 
thumbnail picture 
Title
Price

I would ike to add the SKU number to this list

SkU works fine on the product page itself , and i have modified the code to show after the tilte on a single product display

But its when i have a page full of products - that i would like the SKU to show

Fenori.co.uk 
choose - Products 
Then any category

Thanks

Comment: You wanna to display Sku for All products Page right? what is the all product page ? Shop page or custom template@etaf

Comment: Thanks , Its just a category that shows ALL the products. Basically when a list of products appears on the page I wanted to add the SKU number

Comment: have you try the below code , hook of woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item @etaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this code will helpful for you, the sku will be displayed at the end of shop loop

```
function shop_display_skus() {
global $product;

    if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
        echo '<div class="product-meta">SKU: ' . $product->get_sku() . '</div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_display_skus', 9 );
```